# When changing to cylces my render properties menu changes and is buggy

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am using blender version 2.90.1 even though my issue existed since some version of 2.8.
So when I open my blender file and change the render engine from eve to cycles my menu looks like this:

[image]

even though it should look like this:

[image]

I seem to have the issue with only this one file / project of mine. But I dont know what it is that I did differently here than in other "working" projects.

Please help me. It is just really frustrating to me... Thanks in advance. I am new here and to blender :D